# ERROR: Failed to update svn repo in jenkins output console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I am trying to build a project using jenkins.I am using jenkins pipeline and I have written this code in my jenkinsfile

```
node {
    stage('checkout')
    {
    checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', additionalCredentials: [], excludedCommitMessages: '', excludedRegions: '', excludedRevprop: '', excludedUsers: '', filterChangelog: false, ignoreDirPropChanges: false, includedRegions: '', locations: [[cancelProcessOnExternalsFail: true, credentialsId: '007bee40-b740-4f9f-99a4-f6b505163dd7', depthOption: 'infinity', ignoreExternalsOption: true, local: '.', remote: 'http://34.204.108.229/repos/newrep/branches']], quietOperation: true, workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'UpdateUpdater']])
    }

}
```

But I am getting this error when I build it ERROR: Failed to update http://34.204.108.229/repos/newrep/branches
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E200030: READONLY

Any help would be appreciated